# What to do if the Extended Euclidean Algorithm terminates in one step?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, inverse, euclidean-algorithm

I am trying to solve the linear congruence

> $14x \equiv 1 \pmod{113}$.

So I first find $\gcd(14, 113) = 1$. However this means that:

> $113 = 14(8) + 1$

There is only one step needed. If I don't have any other equations, how do I find the inverse? Thank you for any help!

Comment: So $-8$ is the inverse

Comment: Right, I did get that, but I went to check my answer with Wolfram Alpha, it gave me 105. I have no idea how they got that, the only thing I can think of is 113 - 8 = 105 but I don't see how that is related (unless there is a gap in my knowledge, it's been 4 years since I've done this kind of math.)

Comment: Since $113-8=105,$ $-8\equiv105\bmod113$

Comment: Ohhh, that makes a lot of sense, I should've thought of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $(8,113)=1$, we multiplying the equation by 8 and get
$$
\begin{aligned}
8(14 x) & \equiv 8(1) \\
112 x & \equiv 8 \\
-1 x & \equiv 8 \\
x & \equiv-8 \\
& \equiv 105 \quad(\bmod 113)
\end{aligned}
$$